# python,if,sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x

допустим у нас есть input() и при вводе значения мы введем например: a 1 то оно должно узнать что стоит первая (a) и написать: получил a со значением 1 или же есть входное значение a 0 то оно вывести получил a со значением 0
input() был приведен в качестве примера , в программе все приходит по sockets и то что там приходит нужно разделять , я думал использовать в начале какую-то метку

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [python,input(),if](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1289494/python-input-if)

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Какую метку, что разделять? Если проблема с socket, то при чем тут input? Приведите пример кода, с которым у вас проблема возникла, может хоть так что-то прояснится.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да тут я не много по другому написал ( там я не так как надо объяснил суть ) сейчас приведу код

Comment: @DimaBroLach лучше не задавать несколько раз один и тот же вопрос, а дополнять один. Можно было в первоначальный вопрос (который сейчас закрыт) всю информацию добавить, тогда его можно было бы переоткрыть.

Comment: спасибо, не знал  вот ссылка:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1291664/python-sockets-pyqt#1291664

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1291664/python-sockets-pyqt#1291664